# Search string formatting in Elouqa API

Tags: rest, api, eloqua

I'm using the Elouqa Rest API in an integration with another product and I want to implement a file browser.  As part of this I want to get a list of the folders inside another folder.  The[api documents here](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-REST-1.0-assets-email-folders-get.html) say that a search string can be appended but don't give any clues as to the format of the search string.  I've tried various things but so far I'm just getting empty results.  An example is here:

```
/API/rest/1.0/assets/email/folders?search=folderId+%3D+250
```

I've tried with and without +'s and with and without url encoding the = sign, also various combinations of quote marks but so far nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is a slightly different endpoint e.g.:

```
/API/rest/1.0/assets/email/folder/250/contents
```

Which would provide a list of folders contained with folder 250

If you wanted to search for a given folder name then you would use

```
/API/rest/1.0/assets/email/folders?search=foldername
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Apparently not! - I only discovered this by using a fiddler session whilst navigating folders on the web UI.